# Get row values as column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a single row data-frame like below

```
Num     TP1(USD)    TP2(USD)    TP3(USD)    VReal1(USD)     VReal2(USD)     VReal3(USD)     TiV1 (EUR)  TiV2 (EUR)  TiV3 (EUR)  TR  TR-Tag
AA-24   0       700     2100    300     1159    2877    30       30     47      10  5
```

I want to get a dataframe like the one below

```
ID  Price   Net     Range
1   0       300     30
2   700     1159    30
3   2100    2877    47
```

The logic here is that
a. there will be 3 columns names that contain TP/VR/TV. So in the ID, we have 1, 2 & 3 (these can be generated by extracting the value from the column names or just by using a range to fill)
b. TP1 value goes into first row of column 'Price',TP2 value goes into second row of column 'Price' & so on
c. Same for VR & TV. The values go into 'Net' & 'Range columns
d. Columns 'Num', 'TR'  & 'TR=Tag' are not relevant for the result.

I tried `df.filter(regex='TP').stack()`. I get all the 'TP' column & I can access individual values be index ([0],[1],[2]). I could not get all of them into a column directly.

I also wondered if there may be a easier way of doing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I move certain columns into rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72809395/how-can-i-move-certain-columns-into-rows)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming `'Num'` is a unique identifier, you can use [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['TP', 'VR', 'TV'], i='Num', j='ID')
```

or, for an output closer to yours:

```
out = (pd
 .wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['TP', 'VR', 'TV'], i='Num', j='ID')
 .reset_index('ID')
 .drop(columns=['TR', 'TR-Tag'])
 .rename(columns={'TP': 'Price', 'VR': 'Net', 'TV': 'Range'})
 )
```

output:

```
       ID  Price   Net  Range
Num                          
AA-24   1      0   300     30
AA-24   2    700  1159     30
AA-24   3   2100  2877     47
```

###### updated answer

```
out = (pd
 .wide_to_long(df.set_axis(df.columns.str.replace(r'\(USD\)$', '', regex=True),
                           axis=1),
               stubnames=['TP', 'VReal', 'TiV'], i='Num', j='ID')
 .reset_index('ID')
 .drop(columns=['TR', 'TR-Tag'])
 .rename(columns={'TP': 'Price', 'VReal': 'Net', 'TiV': 'Range'})
 )
```

output:

```
       ID  Price   Net  Range
Num                          
AA-24   1      0   300     30
AA-24   2    700  1159     30
AA-24   3   2100  2877     47
```

Answer (score 5):

let us create a `Multiindex` then use `.stack`

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='TP|VR|TV')
#i couldn't figure out to split by 
#word\number without creating an additional whitespace split.
df1.columns = df1.columns\
     .str.replace('(\d+)', r' \1' ,regex=True).str.split(' ',expand=True)

#or more succinctly.
df1.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df1.columns.str.extract('(\D+)(\d+)'))   

print(df1)

  TP              VR              TV
   1    2     3    1     2     3   1   2   3
0  0  700  2100  300  1159  2877  30  30  47
```

---

```
df1.stack(1).rename(columns={'TP': 'Price', 'VR': 'Net', 'TV': 'Range'})
    
     Price  Range   Net
0 1      0     30   300
  2    700     30  1159
  3   2100     47  2877
```

Answer (score 4):

`pivot_wider` (see [mozway's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067635/13258525)) is probably best here from a pure pandas perspective, but if you need more flexibility, you could also `melt` and `pivot`:

```py
import pandas as pd

# recreating your dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(['AA-24', '0', '700', '2100', '300', '1159', '2877', '30', '30', '47', '10', '5'], 
                  index= ['Num', 'TP1(USD)', 'TP2(USD)', 'TP3(USD)', 'VReal1(USD)', 'VReal2(USD)', 'VReal3(USD)', 'TiV1(EUR)', 'TiV2(EUR)', 'TiV3(EUR)', 'TR', 'TR-Tag']).T

# reshaping the data
(df.melt(id_vars=['Num','TR', 'TR-Tag'])
 .assign(col=lambda x: x['variable'].str[:2], idx=lambda x: x['variable'].str.extract("([0-9])"))
 .pivot(values='value', columns='col', index='idx')
 .rename(columns={'TP': 'Price', 'VR': 'Net', 'Ti': 'Range'})
)
```

Perhaps surprisingly, this is also faster than `wide_to_long`. Benchmarking gives 7.76 ms ± 841 µs per loop for this method.

The `wide_to_long` [approach from mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067635/13258525):

```py
(pd
 .wide_to_long(df.set_axis(df.columns.str.replace(r'\([A-Z]{3}\)$', '', regex=True),
                           axis=1),
               stubnames=['TP', 'VReal', 'TiV'], i='Num', j='ID')
 .reset_index('ID')
 .drop(columns=['TR', 'TR-Tag'])
 .rename(columns={'TP': 'Price', 'VReal': 'Net', 'TiV': 'Range'})
 )
```

benchmarks at 30.4 ms ± 3.07 ms per loop on my machine.

[Umar.H's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73067879/13258525) using `stack` is the faster than both:

```py
df1 = df.filter(regex='TP|VR|TV')
df1.columns = df1.columns\
     .str.replace('(\d+)', r' \1' ,regex=True).str.split(' ',expand=True)
df1.stack(1).rename(columns={'TP': 'Price', 'VR': 'Net', 'TV': 'Range'})
```

Runs at 6.07 ms ± 156 µs per loop

If you don't mind the additional import, [sammywemmy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73068287/13258525) using pyjanitor's `pivot_wider` offers speed and an elegant syntax.

```py
(df
.select_columns('TP*', 'VR*', 'Ti*')
.pivot_longer(index = None, 
              names_to = ('.value', 'ID'), 
              names_pattern = ('(.+)(\d).+'))
.rename(columns = {'TP':'Price', 'VReal':'Net', 'TiV':'Range'})
)
```

benchmarks at 11.2 ms ± 229 µs per loop

and the names pattern approach:

```py
df.pivot_longer(index = None, 
                names_to = ('Price', 'Net', 'Range'), 
                names_pattern = ('TP.*', 'VR.*', 'Ti.*'), 
                ignore_index = False)
```

is the fastest of the lot as tested, coming in at 3.53 ms ± 95 µs per loop.

(It is worth noting that this dataset is probably too small to care about speed, and the order may not be the same on larger datasets)

Answer (score 2):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.select_columns('TP*', 'VR*', 'Ti*')
.pivot_longer(index = None, 
              names_to = ('.value', 'ID'), 
              names_pattern = ('(.+)(\d).+'))
.rename(columns = {'TP':'Price', 'VReal':'Net', 'TiV':'Range'})
)
  ID  Price   Net  Range
0  1      0   300     30
1  2    700  1159     30
2  3   2100  2877     47
```

In the above solution, regex pattern is used to extract the relevant sub labels in the columns ; `.value` determines which of the sub labels remain as headers.

Another solution, that might be useful is to pass a list of regular expressions to `names_pattern` parameter:

```py
df.pivot_longer(index = None, 
                names_to = ('Price', 'Net', 'Range'), 
                names_pattern = ('TP.*', 'VR.*', 'Ti.*'), 
                ignore_index = False)

   Price   Net  Range
0      0   300     30
0    700  1159     30
0   2100  2877     47
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'TP1':[0], 'TP2':[700], 'TP3':[2100], 'VR1':[300], 'VR2':[1159], 'VR3':[2877], 'TV1':[30], 'TV2':[30], 'TV3':[47]})

pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), ["TP", "VR", "TV"], i="index", j="Nr").droplevel('index').rename(columns={'TP': 'Price', 'VR': 'Net', 'TV': 'Range'})
```

Result:

```
    Price   Net  Range
Nr                    
1       0   300     30
2     700  1159     30
3    2100  2877     47
```